# Running into an error while loading javascript in html

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, flatbuffers

Error that I am facing when loading the html file is (in the js console of brave browser):

```
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Module name "constants.js" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at Object.s [as require] (require.js:5)
    at requirejs (require.js:5)
    at flatbuffers.js:4
```

Details follow:

I am working on an html page which requires some `*.js` files. These files are installed locally.

The specific `js` file that I want is `flatbuffers.js` which I have installed in the root of my project using `npm` and this has all the files in `project/node_modules/flatbuffers/js/*` directory. The version installed is `2.0.6`.

My project also depends on `require.js` which I have obtained from [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js).

My directory structure looks as follows:

```
project/
     - 3rdparty/
         - js/
             - require.js
     - docs/
         - index.html
     - node_modules/
         - flatbuffers/
             - js/
                 *.js (all flatbuffer related js files)
```

Contents of my `project/docs/index.html` is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="../3rdparty/js/require.js"></script>

        <!-- flatbuffer schema generated -->
        <script>var exports = {};</script>
        <script src="../node_modules/flatbuffers/js/flatbuffers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that `constants.js` file is present in `project/node_modules/flatbuffers/js/` directory. In fact all the files listed in the above directory are:

```
builder.d.ts
builder.js
byte-buffer.d.ts
byte-buffer.js
constants.d.ts
constants.js
encoding.d.ts
encoding.js
flatbuffers.d.ts
flatbuffers.js
flexbuffers
flexbuffers.d.ts
flexbuffers.js
README.md
types.d.ts
types.js
utils.d.ts
utils.js
```

I am not understanding why `constants.js` is not getting loaded and resulting in the above mentioned error.

If it is of any help, here's the contents of `flatbuffers.js` file:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.ByteBuffer = exports.Builder = exports.Encoding = exports.isLittleEndian = exports.float64 = exports.float32 = exports.int32 = exports.SIZE_PREFIX_LENGTH = exports.FILE_IDENTIFIER_LENGTH = exports.SIZEOF_INT = exports.SIZEOF_SHORT = void 0;
var constants_js_1 = require("./constants.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "SIZEOF_SHORT", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return constants_js_1.SIZEOF_SHORT; } });
var constants_js_2 = require("./constants.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "SIZEOF_INT", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return constants_js_2.SIZEOF_INT; } });
var constants_js_3 = require("./constants.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "FILE_IDENTIFIER_LENGTH", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return constants_js_3.FILE_IDENTIFIER_LENGTH; } });
var constants_js_4 = require("./constants.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "SIZE_PREFIX_LENGTH", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return constants_js_4.SIZE_PREFIX_LENGTH; } });
var utils_js_1 = require("./utils.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "int32", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return utils_js_1.int32; } });
Object.defineProperty(exports, "float32", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return utils_js_1.float32; } });
Object.defineProperty(exports, "float64", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return utils_js_1.float64; } });
Object.defineProperty(exports, "isLittleEndian", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return utils_js_1.isLittleEndian; } });
var encoding_js_1 = require("./encoding.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "Encoding", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return encoding_js_1.Encoding; } });
var builder_js_1 = require("./builder.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "Builder", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return builder_js_1.Builder; } });
var byte_buffer_js_1 = require("./byte-buffer.js");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "ByteBuffer", { enumerable: true, get: function () { return byte_buffer_js_1.ByteBuffer; } });
```

Details of my setup:

```
$ uname -a
Linux khz 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ node --version
v17.6.0

$ npm --version
8.5.1
```

Note that I have started brave using: `brave-browser --allow-file-access-from-files`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what happen if you put the script tag that load `content.js` above the script load `require.js`?

Comment: It results in the **exact** same error.

Comment: Sorry it was `constants.js` not `content.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load a non-AMD module (flatbuffers.js and its dependencies) via an AMD loader (RequireJS). It will not work, sorry